# Liblinear bias greater than 2 improving accuracy?

Tags: classification, libsvm

I don't understand what's going on here..

I'm trying to test classification accuracy using liblinear, here: http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/liblinear/

```
First, I run train.exe with 
train.exe -s 2 -v 5
And combinations of -c -p and -B.

for c, I use 2^-5, 2^-4, ... , 2^5
for p, I use 10^-3, 10^-2, ... , 10^1
for B, I use 0, 1.
```

Then I take the best parameters from all combinations.

```
Say c = 0.25, p = 0.001, B = 1
```

After that, I'm running my training and testing sets with:

```
train.exe -s 2 -c 0.25 -p 0.001 -B 1 TrainingFile
predict.exe TestingFile TrainingFile.model
```

And I get 97.77%

Then I run it again, but with -B 2, and I get higher results still... infact, I get the best with -B 3. On alternate sets, with -B 4.

The documentation doesn't say anything about going above a bias of 1.

---

The data has been rescaled using `svm-scale.exe`, as the documentation suggests. I'm also using the same scaling factors for the `"TestingFile"` as suggested (though I dont think that has bearing).

And I've used `checkdata.py`, which doesn't say format is wrong or anything (visual inspection looks correct as well).

---

Am I not narrowing my initial parameter search down enough? Or is this normal? Any suggestions?

Cheers,
Tim.